# How can I debug a x86 ELF application in gdb on a M1 Macbook?

Tags: x86, arm, gdb, qemu, apple-m1

I am trying to debug a x86 ELF on a M1 Macbook. My current setup is to use qemu in a Linux VM, but qemu does not implement `ptrace`, which makes debugging cross arch binaries significantly harder (no breakpoints and no way to restart binary after setting breakpoints). Is there any other way I could debug x86 binaries on a M1 Mac?

Comment: Have you tried using an x86-64 VM, instead of qemu-user in an AArch64 VM?  I assume that would be slower, if supported at all, but correct emulation of an x86 full machine would of course mean that everything including software breakpoints worked.  And hopefully even hardware watchpoints, if that doesn't force the VM to emulate very slowly.

Comment: It does not work on x86_64's docker container either. I hope we find a way to workaround this.